# Fatal error occurred: "Wrong max deactivate lock item time."

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

When we are trying to list our product on amazon from magneto backend we are getting **Fatal error occurred: "Wrong max deactivate lock item time.".**

we are using M2EPRO version 6.0.3

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be caused by enabled compilation during the upgrade.

To solve you should click "Run Compilation Process" in System -> Tools -> Compilation.

Remember to disable " compilation" option ( System -> Tools -> Compilation) before each upgrade and enable it again once the upgrade process is completed.